# Compiles with NetBeans but can't compile or run from bash

Tags: java, netbeans

I have been researching this for weeks and can't seem to get it figured out.
I have a Java program that I have written using NetBeans. It has several imports or .jar files it relies on. It runs fine in NetBeans. But I can't figure out how to call the .jar files and compile from the bash command line. I am using a Mac. I have read several posts on this and none so far have made sense to me. There are 26 imports being used in the program. I don't know if I need to use Ant or specify -CP or Classpath to compile. Surely I don't have to type each one of the .jar files out to compile this from the bash command line?

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_09-b05)

Comment: If you use classes from every jar, then yes, you need to list every jar in the classpath.

Comment: Can't you just use some type of wildcard to call the containing folder though?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to simply use ant with the `build.xml` in the Netbeans project directory. It should "just work" for you. The project will likely not build WITHOUT Netbeans installed (if you tried moving the project to a different machine, for example), but with Netbeans, it should work out of the box.

If you don't have Ant installed, you'll need to install it.

Addenda:

To build it, if you have Ant installed, you should be able to simply go the project directory, where the `build.xml` file is, and type "ant", and it should build and put stuff in the `dist` directory.

If you go in to the `dist` directory and type `java -jar yourapp.jar`, it should run, because the manifest in the jar will point to the nearby lib jar files. If you want to distribute the app, there are different options for java, such as making a Mac compatible application, or a Windows EXE, you'll need to search for those. Or you can simply distribute the contents of the `dist` directory and write a script to do that whole java -jar yourapp.jar command.

Comment: What do you mean "ant with the build.xml"? I need to be able to run this as a stand alone application on other computers as well. Is that possible? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I tried running ant build.xml in the directory where my project is located. I get " BUILD FAILED Target "build.xml" does not exist in project "surveymonkey".

Comment: Just type `ant`, you don't need the build.xml. You should also go to the Ant site at Apache and read some documentation on Ant.

Comment: I know, I need to read a lot of documentation. But at the same time I am also on a time crunch at work to get this done. But I'm learning! Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 1.6 or above, you can toss all 26 jar files into a folder and simply add

```
-cp folder_name/*
```

as your classpath argument.

Some other options are 1.) type all 26 jar files on the command line (using the -cp argument as you have mentioned) 2.) use Ant or Maven or some other build tool and list those 26 jar files in the config file for said build tool or 3.) write a quick-and-dirty shell script that will set the CLASSPATH environment variable for you and then run your javac command.

Comment: I like the sound of the shell script option. As my Java program will be called from a shell script. What might the shell script look like. Thank you!

Comment: Forgive my lack of Mac knowledge, I primarily use cygwin.  But I will try: if you are going with the option of putting all of the jars into a single folder (which they probably already are), then you could just have a one-liner.  Something like `javac -cp folder_name/*.jar $(find . -name *.java)`.  If you are thinking of the CLASSPATH option, then your script could look something like `CLASSPATH='myjar.jar:myother.jar....'` on the first line, and then the second line could just be `javac $(find . -name *.java)`